# C# access modifier for exposing class only within namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

In java you have package level protection that ensures classes are only usable within the package.

Namespaces in C# act more or less like packages. But C# does not have a protection level for protecting classes within a namespace.

Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: c# has assemblies, and you can use the `internal` keyword.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is no such access modifier: the closest modifier is `internal`, but the unit of protection is the assembly in which the class resides, not its namespace.

One could argue that it is possible to achieve similar level of control using `internal`, because both kinds of restriction keep outsiders from accessing the implementation details of your library. The only person to whom it makes a difference is you, the writer of the library, and you are in full control of what to expose and what to hide anyway. Essentially, it means that if you do not want to use a class outside its namespace, simply refrain from using it; if the class is `internal`, nobody else will be able to use that class either.

Comment: This is true. But you might want to hide implementation details to consumers of the code that build the library. I was primarily wondering myself why the difference exists.

Comment: @Jaco If you want to hide a class from others who write code for the same assembly with your class, these are presumed to be your co-workers. If they start using your internal classes, you could walk over to them and have a nice peaceful conversation explaining the dangers of using something that wasn't meant for them to be used :-)

Comment: You can't hide anything because one gets decompiler and sees all they need. Seriously, Namespace regulates nothing. It is like foldering in your PC. Class access modifier regulates everything. As a matter of fact, if you have namespace with no public type in it, when assembly is referenced, you will not even see that namespace.

Comment: @T.S. By "hide" I mean the same exact "hide" as package-private hiding in Java. Otherwise the comparison wouldn't be apples to apples. Of course there's nothing you can do about reflection and decompiling, short of running your code through an obfuscator.

Comment: 'The only person to whom it makes a difference is you, the writer of the library, and you are in full control of what to expose and what to hide anyway. Essentially, it means that if you do not want to use a class outside its namespace, simply refrain from using it' - compiler support for information hiding is a good thing. You definitely want to practice information hiding in any level of the code.

Comment: _"Essentially, it means that if you do not want to use a class outside its namespace, simply refrain from using it"_: I always want to protect myself from myself. `not using` is way more error prone than `If there's a will, there's a way`. Your compiler is your assistant; help him with input (like proper access modifiers) in order to help you. If simply not using something would be good-enough for 1-man-projects, one could just go all public. As a general rule: You are your worst enemy.

Comment: `Essentially, it means that if you do not want to use a class outside its namespace, simply refrain from using it` - following this logic we wouldn't use the `private` access modifier either... So I disagree with it :). Data hiding is important even when I'm the only developer. Just think of troubleshooting a production bug that involves non-`private` data-structures. The headache... :)

Answer (score 3):

In .NET there are assemlies(dll or exe files), you can use `internal` modifier to limit access only within the same assembly

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a specific reason for this?

Mostly, it's because there are some key [differences between packages and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9249357/2630934)

To simplify what's already been said in the linked question and here: Namespaces in C# are mostly to help with organizing an assembly's contents, both internally and externally.  Java packages have more in common with C# assemblies, and there is an access modifier in C# that restricts to the assembly level: [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).