# Accessing internal methods of nested namespace

Tags: c#, .net

Is is possible access function `ConvertData()` from function `TestFunc()`?

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
  internal static class Convert
  {
    internal static int ConvertData()
    {
      //code
    }
  }
}
```

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Test
{
  public class TestDataType
  {
    public void TestFunc()
    {
      int x = Convert.ConvertData()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just try it, if you got the code? Also, do you mean regular access or "ignore all those compile time rules by using reflection" access?

Comment: AFAIK the `internal` keyword specifies that the type/method can only be accessed in the same _assembly_ that it's defined in. The namespace it exists in does not affect its visibility. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: Given that you've called the second bit `TestFunc` - is this for unit testing type stuff?  That's one of the good reasons for using [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Namespaces are irrelevant here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467965/c-sharp-access-modifier-for-exposing-class-only-within-namespace), they are just a convenient way to arrange class and allow two classes to have the same name (as long as they are not in the same Namespace). Imagine that your hard drive doesn't allow folder and *all the files* are at the root level in `c:\`! Without Namespaces, it's the same mess. (But unlike the folders of your hard drive, namespaces doesn't have access restrictions).

`internal` [accessibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels) is relative to [assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/). You can access `internal` members if both declaration and usage codes are in the same assembly ([example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/26itrl)).

If declaration and usage are in different assemblies (let's say it's declared in `A` and used in `A.Test`, a common case), **yes** it is feasible to access `internal` members declared in `A` from `A.Test`.

One achieves this by promoting the using assembly (`A.Test`) as a [friend assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend) of the declaring assembly (`A`).

The promotion is done in `A` by adding this code: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("A.Test")]` anywhere in `A` code, but `AssemblyInfo.cs` is the preferred spot.