# Is the meaning of "package" the same in UML as in Java?

Tags: java, uml, package-diagram

For the purposes of a [UML Package Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram) should each package in Java be considered a package? In Java each "package" is essentially a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) and you can have two different classes (eg `A` & `B`) *both* in the **same** Java package (eg `com.example.my`) *but* in **different** JARs (eg. `API` & `Domain`):

Are Java packages the same thing as packages in UML within the context of a Package Diagram? If not, what is the definition of a package in UML?

Comment: A package is not a namespace.

Comment: @AdamArold are they not equal? I mean package in Java and namespce in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java

Comment: @AdamArold There are differences, but they are analogues of each other and serve the same purpose with rather minor differences, however the question would still remain with C# namespaces and UML packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rahman has given a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053511/254477) already. One thing I would like to mention, is that UML is programming-language and platform independent. So both definitions of a package are not the same.

An UML package can contain jar files, (as can be seen your example) *but* it can **also** contain devices, execution environments and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the design - I don't believe there is any rule saying that Java packages and UML packages need to be mapped one to one - nor there is any rule that says the opposite.

Both Java packages and an UML packages are intended to group similar objects together. But Java packages are for grouping **code** while UML packages are for grouping **models**. And the relation between a model and the code implementation doesn't necessarily have to be one to one and neither do their packages.

Source of info: Software Design courses taken at University.