# C# : Beginning with the syntax?

Tags: c#, syntax, namespaces

I'm a beginner at C#, I used to program with java, I wonder what does `name_1` in this syntax mean?

```
namespace name_1
{
    public class name_2
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Is it the package? Or what? It's in all the project files... Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it writes, `name_1` is a [`namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx).

Comment: `namespace` is similar to `package` in Java. Check this for a side-by-side comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java