# MonoDevelop 4.0.1: Creating a new namespace in a project (on Windows 8.1 64-bit)

Tags: c#, namespaces, monodevelop

How do I create a namespace on MonoDevelop 4.0.1 for the same project?

I am following along the exercises from [Practice Exercises C# Sharp](http://practiceexercisescsharp.blogspot.ca/) where there are 11 lessons with multiple exercises each, and so far I am using only one namespace in the project. Instead of having all the programs I'd work on in the same namespace, I want to create multiple namespaces to make my project folder more organized.

I have more experience in Java, where you organize your source code and classes in independent packages. At one point, I came across this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java) where it only tells me the difference between a Java package and a C# namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C#, the namespace is declared in the source file:

```
 namespace My.Namespace.Name
 {
 }
```

You can have as many of those blocks as you want in a file and you do not need to have a matching folder structure like you do in Java.

Comment: *You can have as many of those blocks as you want in a file* And you can have multiple namespaces in multiple files... it is X * Y :-)

Comment: That doesn't change the way on how the Solutions Pane looks, does it? I was expecting that some of my programs would be nested and thus I can expand and collapse nested namespaces.

Comment: Nope, that does not change the way the solution pane looks.  The solution pane shows the actual files that are in the solution, not the namespaces.  If you want to add nested file structure in the Solution Explorer, just add actual folders to the source directory.

Comment: There is a MonoDevelop toolbox type thing that allows you to browse your classes as a class hierarchy with their methods and properties listed; they are organized by namespace.