# APCS Magpie and Magpie runner call

Tags: java

Why doesn't magpierunner need to import and call magpie, instead just use it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A simple class to run the Magpie class.
 */
public class MagpieRunner2
{

    /**
     * Create a Magpie, give it user input, and print its replies.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Magpie2 maggie = new Magpie2();

        System.out.println (maggie.getGreeting());
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String statement = in.nextLine();

        while (!statement.equals("Bye"))
        {
            System.out.println (maggie.getResponse(statement));
            statement = in.nextLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you missed some code there?

Comment: this is my full code @prudhvi. it never call the magpie2 class though, but still works

Answer (score 0):

If both your magpie and magpie runner are in the same package you don't have to import. Import only if the class your need to access is in different package.

Answer (score 0):

So first off you've left off a lot of context in your question that makes it difficult to answer, but I think I get what you're trying to ask so here it goes.

I believe that you have two classes inside of the same package, Magpie and MagpieRunner. Magpie is probably an object with some properties and methods applied to it. And MagpieRunner is probably where you main lives that will then instantiate your Magpie object and use some of these properties and methods that Magpie exposes to it.

I believe your question is why you don't need to import your Magpie class and you can directly use it in the MagpieRunner.

This is because, if my assumptions above are correct, your Magpie class and MagpieRunner class live in the same package and Magpie is a public class. In some IDE's (Eclipse for example) you can add a class directly to a Java Project and then it lives in the "default package." But any public class in a package is accessible without using an import by another class in that package.

I hope that helps!

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want to know. So is that just a java thing that you don't have to import?

Comment: As long as you have a public class that lives in the same package as your main then no you don't have to import the class. But if you have a class that doesn't live in the same package then you **do** need to import the class. I'm sure I would be writing for a very long time to describe how lots of programming languages handle class linking. That being said I know C# handles it relatively similar to Java see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249357/difference-between-namespace-in-c-sharp-and-package-in-java) StackOverflow question.